# Adding <p> to an unformated text in angular

Tags: angularjs, wysiwyg, copy-paste, summernote

I am pasting pure text like the follow, just inside a textbox of  summernote and process it to remove all html format. but I need to process it again to update the model adding `<p>` to paragraphs and remove empty lines.

**This is what I have**

```
Example Test
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.

Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
```

And...

**This is what I need:**

```
<p>Example Test</p>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
<p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
<p>Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
```

**This is my view:**

```
<div summernote config="options" ng-model="post.description" on-paste="snPaste(evt)"></div>
```

**And this is the script I am using for pasting:**

```
$scope.snPaste = function(e) {
    //First define the clean content
    var cleanUp = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');

    //Have it wait for 0.5 seconds to update the pasted
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.post.description = cleanUp; //Here I update the model.
        });
    }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the result:

[image: result]

Here's the tweak to your controller:

```
angular.module('summernoteDemo', ['summernote'])
  .controller('CodeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.snPaste = function(e) {
      //First define the clean content
      clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
      var cleanUp = clipboardData.getData('Text');

      //Have it wait for 0.5 seconds to update the pasted
      setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.post.description = '<p>' + cleanUp.replace(/\r\n\r\n|\n\n/g, '</p><p>').replace(/\r\n|\n/g, '</p><p>') + '</p>'; //Here you update the model.
        });
      }, 500);
    };
  });
```

Here's a working JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/nkosyafs/.

Comment: Hello Pal, I tried to paste pure code, but it didn't work, it added `<p>` just at the start and the end, not in the lines between end and start.

Comment: I thought you were just pasting text.  Send me what you're trying to paste.

Comment: @AbielMuren Did you need further help with this?

Comment: Sorry, yes I need it, try to paste the example above, for some reason only adds `<p>` at the very beginning and the very end. Try to copy paste a list for example the list in the side meny if this site. And It will remove the format and add `<p>` but just in the beginning  and in the end.

Comment: @AbielMuren Looks like browser compatibility issues, I updated my answer and the JSFiddle.  Take a look now, and let me know.

Comment: No worries, happy to help!  Let me know if you need anything else.